# How to use Quasar date.FormatDate in Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, quasar-framework, ts-jest

I have this function:

```
import {date as DateUtils} from 'quasar'

    export class FormatDate {
      static dateTime(date: Date) : string {
            return dateUtils.formatDate(date, "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss")
          }
    }
```

that I'm trying to test with Jest like:

```
    it('Should get the correct formatted date', () => {
        const date = DateUtils.buildDate({year: 2021, month: 11, date: 28, hours: 12, minutes: 11})
        expect(FormatDate.dateTime(date)).toEqual('28.11.2021 12:11:00')
    })
```

But, when I run the test, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

    at Object.formatDate (/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.cjs.prod.js:6:132667)
    at Function.dateTime (/src/components/FormatDate.ts:6:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/test/jest/__tests__/FormatDate.spec.ts:19:34)
    at Object.asyncJestTest (/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
    at /node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at mapper (/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
    at /node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Doesn anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide a full error stack. Which line throws this error?

Comment: This line throws at dateUtils.formatDate. I added the error stack

Answer (score 0):

Normally this can be solved through configurating quasar in a local vue instance:

```
import { Quasar } from "quasar";
import langEn from "quasar/lang/en";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Quasar, {}, { lang: langEn });
```

A similar issue was discussed in the [quasar project](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-testing/issues/67).

Buuuut, i'm curious if someone would have an additional solution.

Because i for myself have a similar issue, but in another context.

Through a terrible architecture (please do not ask why) our project is using the date helpers outside of the vue component contexts. As part of a simple functional helper for example. Like:

```
const defaultDateFormat = (date: Date): string => formatDate(date, "whatever-pattern");
```

Running a test on this results in the same issue described by the author.

The described solution before does not apply here.

In short:

- using a quasar date formatter outside of a vue component
- running a jest test on this helper
- fails

So, if anyone has an idea my ears are open.